# Converting LINQ to XML result to generic list in VB.NET. Odd error

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, generics, linq-to-xml

I have a function that works great in C# that I'm converting to VB.NET. I'm having an issue converting the result set to a generic list in VB.NET.

The code:

```
    Public Function GetCategories() As List(Of Category)
        Dim xmlDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("http://my_xml_api_url.com")
        Dim categories = (From category In xmlDoc.Descendants("Table") _
        Select New Category()).ToList(Of Category)()

        Return categories
    End Function
```

The error occurs when converting the result via .ToList(Of Category)(). The error:

> Public Function ToList() As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of TSource)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is not generic (or has no free type parameters) and so cannot have type arguments.

Category is a simple object I've created, stored in the App_Code directory.

I have the necessary "Imports System.Collections.Generic" reference in the file, so I don't see why I can't convert the result set to a generic list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's saying that because you're invoking it as an extension method on an `IEnumerable<Category>`, the type argument has already been specified. Just get rid of the type argument:

```
Dim categories = (From category In xmlDoc.Descendants("Table") _
                  Select New Category()).ToList()
```

That's equivalent to writing:

```
Dim categories = Enumerable.ToList(Of Category) _
    (From category In xmlDoc.Descendants("Table") _
     Select New Category())
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple: Replace `ToList(Of Category)()` with `ToList()`.

As a side note: Maybe you want `New Category(category)` instead of `New Category()`? At the moment, your code is creating a list of *empty* categories...

Comment: Excellent point and +1 for ya. I used a C# to VB converter that stripped the section assigning values to the category object. I added that back in and all is well. Thanks!